# Where am I going wrong in in solving this inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have to find the domain of

> $$\sqrt{\log_{0.5}\frac{x}{x^2-1}}$$

As the under root quantity must be positive,

$$\frac{x}{x^2-1}\leq1\implies\frac{x^2-x-1}{(x+1)(x-1)}\geq0\\\implies x\in(-\infty,-1]\cup\left[\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2},1\right]\cup\left[\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2},\infty\right).$$

But this in incorrect. Where is it wrong?

Comment: You also need
$$\frac{x}{x^2-1} > 0$$

Comment: @quasi Thanks... I have got it...:-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve  two inequalities:
$$0<\frac{x}{x^2-1}\leq1.$$
The first one is necessary because the argument of the logarithm should be positive. So according to your partial solution, you should remove the set $(-\infty,-1]\cup [0,1]$ and therefore the domain is
$$\left[\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2},0\right)\cup\left[\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2},+\infty\right).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have solved it (from the comment below the question) already but anyways thanks;-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$\log_{0.5}\frac{x}{x^2-1}=\log_{2} \frac{x^2-1}{x}\ge 0 \overbrace{\Rightarrow}^{x\ne 0,\ \ x\ne \pm1} \\
\frac{x^2-1}{x}\ge 1 \Rightarrow \frac{x^2-x-1}{x}\ge 0 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\le x<0 \ \ \text{or} \ \ \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\le x. $$

Answer (score 0):

$\log(0.5) < 0$, so logs to base 0.5 have reversed signs.

Comment: I have reversed the signs... haven't I?I have used the fact that $\log_{0.5}x$ is a decreasing function.